# React state changing unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, immutability

Assume there are two states which is the same object, in some point of time using `setState` for one object also changes the other object in state.

Let me explain it with the code;

```
export default class AgentDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {x: 1, y:1 }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        let theObject = {
            someKey: 'someValue'
        }

        this.setState({
            x: theObject,
            y: theObject // I also tried with Object.create(theObject) and Object.assign({}, theObject)
        })

        this.changeStates()
    }

    changeStates() {

        let otherObject = {
            someKey: 'someOtherValue'
        }

        this.setState({
            x: otherObject
        })

        console.log(this.state.y) // { someKey: 'someOtherValue' }

    }

}
```

I expect y to be 'someValue' but it mutates with x and I couldn't find the connection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It **does not** mutate with `x`. The `setState` method [is not sync](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), see the red note: you are simply inspecting `y` too soon. You can use a callback to do something when the state has been changed: `this.setState(..., function() { console.log(this.state.y); });`.

Comment: @lorenzo-s yeah i know `setState`is asynchronous process but it doesn't matter if I log `y` in the `setState` callback the result is the same.

Comment: Too me, it's ok, I tested your same code **[here](https://jsbin.com/sicufidima/edit?js,console)**. If you still have problems, look at your whole code, maybe there's some side-effect somewhere.